# Running project with debug takes extremely long to load

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols

For some reason, my Silverlight project in VS2010 recently started to take forever to load, upwards of even 10min or so. Sometimes it won't ever load as far as I can tell, and just hangs on the silverlight loading screen with the blue dots in a circle animation. But before it even gets to that point, it painfully spends a solid 10 seconds or so for each symbols file it loads. So in the output I'll get:

```
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Then 10 seconds later I'll get the next one, and there's about 50 of them. **The weird thing is that when I run the project with my internet disabled, it loads extremely quickly.** Each one of those symbols loaded statements flies by, and before I know it I'm looking at my running Silverlight project. My teammate things it might have to do with Perforce, which is how we manage our source, and which we have a plugin for in Visual Studio.

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? Or experienced a similar phenomenon once? It randomly started yesterday.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using the built-in VS Server to host my project, if that's relevant.

**Resolved: We don't know exactly what caused the issue, but it was network related and fixed itself. I just hope it doesn't happen again.**

Comment: What is your default browser?

Comment: My whole team is fighting this as well. We are not using Silverlight, but since migrating our web project from vs2005 to vs2010 we have 10 min page load times when debugging. For example, we compile, the sign-in page comes up, we sign into our web site, then navigate to some page ... and as stated above the output window is loading symbols and it can take up to 10 mins. Following page hits are quicker after this and more we use vs2010 during the day the better it gets, but the next morning we are stuck again. Can you provide more details as to the work around? Thanks!
TimT

Comment: @JoeCool : You should add an answer, even if not complete, and accept it, if it resolved your issue. It may be edited afterward if people come with a more precise cause.

Answer (score 2):

You might be downloading symbols from MSDN or some other server. Check Option -> Debugging -> Symbols and make sure you don't have any locations active.